# How to decode 16-bit signed binary file in IEEE754 standard

Tags: matlab, binary, decoding, ieee-754

I have a file format called .ogpr (openGPR, a dead format used for Ground Radar data), I'm trying to read this file and convert it into a matrix using Matlab(R).

In the first part of file there is a JSON Header where are explained the characteristics of data acquisition (number of traces, position etc), and on the second part there are two different data blocks.
First block contains the 'real' GPR data and I know that they are formatted as:

1. Multibyte binary data are little-endian
2. Floating point binary data follow the IEEE 754 standard
3. Integer data follow the two’s complement encoding

I know also the total number of bytes and also the relative number of bytes for each single 'slice' (we have 512 samples * 10 channel * 3971 slices [x2 byte per sample]).
Furthermore: 'A Data Block of type Radar Volume stores a 3D array of radar Samples At the moment, each sample value is stored in a 16-bit signed integer. Each Sample value is in volts in the range [-20, 20].'

Second block contains geolocation infos.

I'd like to read and convert the Data Block from that codification but it ain't clear especially how many bytes break the data and how to convert them from that codification to number.

I tried to use this part of code:

```
bin_data = ogpr_data(48:(length(ogpr_data)-1),1);
writematrix(bin_data, 'bin_data.txt');
fileID = fopen('bin_data.txt', 'r', 'ieee-le');
format = 'uint16';
Data = fread(fileID, Inf, format);fclose(fileID)
```

Comment: Your explanation of the file format is good, but not good enough so that we can write actual code to parse it. Is it possible you provide a (consistent) sample of the file? Also, does your code work? If not, what's the issue?

Comment: Sure @Arc, thank you. 

[Link to data](http://sendanywhe.re/6UTSOCKX)


Right now, this part of code is working, but the results are not good. I obtain a series of 5 numbers for n rows...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your posted code is mixing text files and binary files. The writematrix( ) routine writes values as comma delimited text. Then you turn around and try to use fopen( ) and fread( ) to read this as a binary file in IEEE Little Endian format. These are two totally different things. You need to pick one format and use it consistently, either human readable comma delimited text files, or machine readable binary IEEE format files.

Comment: Sure, actually I already work with these data at different mode. I did not report the first part of my code where I work on file header.
First part (rows 1 to 47) it's just the header, I need to works on 'Data Block' (rows 38 to end-1) that they are in IEEE Little Endian format.